# why the program doesn’t work when CL_LOCAL_MeM_FENCE is included in the IF loop

Tags: opencl

```
while ( size!=0)
{
  if(local_id<size)
    local_sums[local_id] += local_sums[local_id+size];
  work_group_barrier(clk_local_mem_fence)
  size = size/2;
}
```

In the while loop  the CL_LOCAL_MeM_FENCE  was included in the IF loop..The task was to identify the mistake and comment why the program doesn’t work when CL_LOCAL_MeM_FENCE  is included in the IF loop

I'm learning GPU programming related to my course.Above i had provided all details about my query.I didn't understand why the program doesn’t work when CL_LOCAL_MeM_FENCE  is included in the IF loop. Please, someone help me out.Thanks advance.

Comment: there is only summation in "if".

Answer (score 2):

In OpenCL, all work-items in a workgroup must execute the same number of barriers of each type. When a work item encounters its first fence, it waits until all others have reached their first fence; when it reaches the second, it waits until all others have reached fence 2, and so on.

If you have a fence inside a conditional (if, switch, …) block, this usually means the condition must be the same on all work-items, and if you have a fence inside a loop (for, while, do, etc.), all work-items must run the same number of iterations.

It technically doesn't matter where a particular fence is in the code (i.e. you could have a barrier in both the if and the else part of a condition), but it helps to follow those rules for readability.